# Android Studio Application crashing when navigating to Google maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am facing error when trying to navigate to the activity containing the Google maps. When navigating to the mapping activity it says, Unfortunately [application Name] has stopped Please advise.

**AndroidManifest.xml**
   `

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DriverScoreActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CarHealthActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

`

**Layout Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DriverScoreActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="samtechme.come.smartobd.VehicleLocationActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Display Map Code**

```
 private void DisplayMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
    if (mMap != null) {
        // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                25.023395, 55.090513));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);

        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
             1521-1521/samtechme.come.smartobd E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
        at samtechme.come.smartobd.DriverScoreActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DriverScoreActivity.java:213)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
```

Comment: I have added the logcat, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your `Map` is not ready yet when you commit your Fragment and you are getting `null` when you use `getMap()` function.

The method to overcome this issue is described here in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109093/1016462

Comment: You have to implement the callback and implement the method `onMapReady()`. In this method you should be able to get the map using `getMap()` function like you did in your code and it should not crash.

Answer (score 0):

you declared `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` in xml, but you are using `MapFragment` cast in `DisplayMap()`. Change

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```