# Setmylocationenabled(true) does not show my location android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

So the title pretty much explains what is the error that I have can anyone help me please? this is what I have, i'm newbie to android or is it another way to get my location as soon as i open the mapfragment? thank you

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class RutaTinaja extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapas);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

While enabled and the location is available, the my-location layer continuously draws an indication of a user's current location and bearing, and [displays UI controls](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/feffd7e0dbb62c412b0b54a47256b09074c694cb/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/UiSettingsDemoActivity.java) that allow a user to interact with their location (for example, to enable or disable camera tracking of their location and bearing).
In order to use the my-location-layer feature you need to request permission for either ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION orACCESS_FINE_LOCATION unless you have set a [custom location source](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/feffd7e0dbb62c412b0b54a47256b09074c694cb/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LocationSourceDemoActivity.java).

If you have set a custom location source via setLocationSource(LocationSource) the Google Maps Android API will not check whether the above permissions have been granted. However, you still need to make sure that the user has granted all the permissions required for your custom location source.

Firstly, make sure your API Key is valid and add this into your manifest :

Here is a simple [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595) that asks for the user’s location then centers the map on their location once it becomes known:

And please refer to the following this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789758
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109093

Hope it helps.